# l want to call up (y) from function (sum) to function (supstract) How do i do it?

Tags: python

```
class Number:
 def __init__(self,x):

   Self.x=x
 def sum(self):
  y=input(" enter num one")
  s=self.x+y
  print(s)
 def supstract():
  W=self.x-y
  print(w)
call_up=Number(10)
call_up.sum()
call_up.supstract()
```

I want to call up `y` from function `sum` to function `supstract` can you help about it please?

Comment: Python is case-sensitive. `Y` is not the same as `y`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but maybe you can assign `self.y` in `sum()` and then use that in `supstract()`.

Comment: I thought this would error on `Self` because it should be `self`, but no, it errors even earlier. At `×`, which should be `x`. So many errors here before you actually get to the part you ask about.

Comment: The word is "subtract", not "supstract".  And you need "self" as an argument in that function.

Comment: Now i edit it can you solve my question now

Comment: Once `sum` is finished, the `y` variable is gone.  As a general rule, you shouldn't do I/O in a class member like this.  Have the member function do the computation, but have the global code do the I/O.  That way, you can pass the input to multiple functions.

Comment: You mean the y variable should be global

Answer (score -1):

I think this fixes all the errors in your code and does what you wanted to do:

```
class Number:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x=x
    def sum(self,y):
        s=self.x+y
        print(s)
    def subtract(self,y):
        w=self.x-y
        print(w)

call_up=Number(10)
y=int(input("enter num one"))
call_up.sum(y)
call_up.subtract(y)
```

Comment: How to save in python

Comment: How to save what?

Comment: I work in a project in Python and asked about the following, did you understand something of this want me to create a function name save in Class and I did not understand what is meant

Comment: I work in a project in Python and asked about the following, did you understand something of this want me to create a function name save in Class and I did not understand what is meant.                                            Save: which can be called as obj.save .. here we need first to initiate new employee
object like this obj = Employee(Dictionary) employee info should be managed same
as create

Comment: That is an ENTIRELY different question from the one you asked here.  You need to ask a new question.